# Using .bind and .unbind to move a li

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to figure out how I can use bind to move the selected li's from box1 to box2 and from box2 back to box1. Stuck on this and need some help. Also when a li is selected and moved over to the next box by clicking <kbd>Move Right</kbd>, they stack on every click. How can I fix that?

code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".box1 ul li").click(function(){
               if($(this).hasClass("active-li")==true)
               {
                    $(this).removeClass("active-li");
               }
               else
               {
                    $(this).addClass("active-li");
               }
            });
            $(".box1 ul li").click(function(){
                 var x=$(this).data("drink");
                 $("#btt1").click(function(){
                    $(".box2 ul").append(x);
                    $(x).bind("click", bindLi);
                    
                    
                }); 
            });
            $(x).bind("click", bindLi);
        });
            
        
        function bindLi(){
            alert("hello");
        }
```

CSS:

```
        .box1{border:1px solid black; width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin-top:100px; margin-left:50px;}
        .box2{border:1px solid black; width:200px; height:200px; float:left; margin-top:100px; margin-left:100px;}
        .button-container{width:80px; height:30px; float:left; margin-top:200px; margin-left:100px;}
        .active-li{background-color:yellow;}
        ul li:hover{cursor:pointer;}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="box1" id="box1">
        <ul>
            <li data-drink="beer">
               Beer 
            </li>
            <li data-drink="water">
               Water 
            </li>
            <li data-drink="soda">
                Soda
            </li>
            <li data-drink="juice">
                Juice
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <input type="button" id="btt1" name="btt1" value="Move Right" />
        <input type="button" id="btt2" name="btt2" value="Move Left" />
    </div>
    <div class="box2" id="box2">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/fgo455zt/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please take a look at below code:

https://jsfiddle.net/fgo455zt/5/

We can simply the code as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".box1 ul li, .box2 ul li").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active-li"); //highlight the clicked li
  });

  $("#btt1, #btt2").click(function() {
    var sourceUL = null;
    var targetUL = null;
    //depending upon which button clicked we are moving selected li to and from source to target UL
    if ($(this).attr("id") == "btt1") {
      sourceUL = $(".box1 ul");
      targetUL = $(".box2 ul");
    } else {
      sourceUL = $(".box2 ul");
      targetUL = $(".box1 ul");
    }

    $(sourceUL).find("li.active-li").each(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active-li"); //removing the active class before moving the li
      $(targetUL).append($(this));
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: awesome thank you! Would bind, unbind make things more cumbersome?

Comment: thanks @MattPicca. `$.bind` and `$.unbind` will complicate the current code. Generally we use `$.unbind` when any particular  `event` is getting broadcast by some other piece of code and we want to avoid our own event listen being executed. But in your case the requirement is quite different.

Comment: Okay, i see now. Thank you @vijayP for the help, its much appreciated.